# Send invitations to multiple mails with devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My user model has 2 email addresses `email` and `email2`. I was thinking send to one email and then the other, but the invitation token of the first mail would be invalidated when I call the invite for the second email.
How can I do this? Thanks in adavnce

Comment: What is the use case for having email2? (in other words: Why do you need to send an invitation to both?) How is the whole invitation process triggered? You should keep answering the question "why?" until it's painfully obvious there's no further answer. Right now you've explained the immediate problem you have, but not what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gregmac Actually there are client requirements. The reason: the invitations are not made by the users themselves, but for other profile type in the system (let's call an admin), so if the first email never receive the invitation(typo problems of the admin, account closed, etc) the user could receive it in the second email.

Comment: Why is your app responsible for handling the failure of another system to have correct data? Why would the second email be correct when the first isn't? Why not have email3, email4, email5 for the same reasons? Do all users have a second email address? What happens if they don't? Are these accounts provisioned by the user themselves? Seems to me like if the user doesn't get an invitation due to their email being invalid, then they can contact a help desk and the help desk should fix their invalid email, not add a crazy requirement to all other software to handle and use two email accounts.

Comment: @gregmac Yeah, you're right, but anyway is something we already told to the client that we're gonna make. We couldn't say now that their requirement won't be done because the users should be careful, specially when we already charged for that.